# Replacing drop down search menu with multiple links for form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is what I'm hoping to do. Currently I have a drop down list of characteristics from which user can choose and search does certain element holds that characteristic. He picks a characteristic from drop down menu and clicks search button. Now I am trying to make a list of links for those characteristics so user can immediately click on certain characteristic.

I will have a couple of links separated with `|`:

```
characteristic1_link | characteristic2_link | characteristic3_link
```

Currently I have the following for drop down search which works:

```
<%= form_for(@element, method: 'get', url: 'query') do |f| %>  
  <%= f.collection_select :characteristic_id, Characteristic.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => true %>
  <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to do that with links which I generate like this:

```
<% @characteristics.each do |characteristic| %>
    <%= link_to (characteristic.name), '#' %>
<% end %>
```

How can I pass `:characteristic_id` parameter with link and somehow make `f.submit` to trigger when user clicks on link?

**EDIT:**

This seems to be working:

```
<% @characteristics.each do |characteristic| %>
    <%= link_to (characteristic.name), query_path(:element => {:characteristic_id => characteristic.id}) %>
<% end %>
```

Opinions about this method? :)

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question like that clicking and link_to-anchor selects the option with the same name as the anchors label and submits the form then you might want to...

```
<%= link_to characteristic.name, '#', class: 'trigger_select' %>
```

and let your JS do the rest. (untested.)

```
$('.trigger_select').click( function() { 
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#select_field').val(href);
    $('#form').submit();
});
```

hope i understood you correcly.

Comment: Yes, something like that. So, if I have 20 links, I would need to generate 20 forms?

Comment: no, actually you`d still have 1 form, and 20 links. each links click is recignized by JS and would perform the select field to change.
IF you just want to make the links act like a form, then use button_to instead of link_to, and style it.